# How to get internal id of Tax Code in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I added some custom fields  to the Tax Code. Now I want to use values of custom fields related to the tax code  via Suitescript. In the record browser this record doesn't appear.  So how could I get record id of tax code directly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enabled the Show Internal IDs feature in Set Preferences.  This will show the internal ID for every record when you are in list view. With this feature active you will see the tax code in the left column in list view.